# Using having after grouping by a rand is not returnig expected results

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, group-by

AFAIK `having` statement is executed after `group by` (if present, otherwise it works like a simple `where`), so it can be used to filter grouped rows, but i'm facing a strange behavior issue I can't resolve.

I need to filter grouped rows that have been grouped with a `round()` function but the returned results are not the ones I expected.

##### The example

Given my dataset as

| val |
| --- |
| 13 |
| 15 |
| 21 |
| 27 |
| 34 |
| 41 |

and running the following query

```sql
select
  round(val, -1) as v,
  sum(1) as cnt
from
  dataset
group by
  round(val, -1)
having
  v > 10
;
```

I would expect to have the resulset as

| v | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |
| 30 | 2 |
| 40 | 1 |

but instead it returns 0 rows.

Link to sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/647daf/4

Comment: Looks like a version-specific bug (5.6.48 and 5.6.51 reproduces the issue). MySQL ver. 8.0.27, 5.7.35 and even 5.5.62 produces correct output.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the "alias", you have

```
HAVING round(val, -1) > 10
```

`round(val, -1)`  is 10 so it is excluded from the results.

Run `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...;  SHOW WARNINGS;`  It may show another thing -- namely that the `HAVING` clause may have been moved (by the Optimizer) to `WHERE`.

Yes, there is a fixed order for things in `SELECT`, mostly following the order in which they 'must' be performed.  Still the Optimizer is free to rearrange *as long as the result will be the same*.

```
FROM
WHERE    -- the main place where an INDEX can avoid some work
GROUP BY
HAVING   -- can be moved to WHERE if no aggregates
ORDER BY -- an INDEX may move this to GROUP BY or even obviate it
OFFSET   -- alas, no optimization here
LIMIT
```

If you had said `HAVING val > 10`, you would have uncovered a bug.